# ADM equations with cosmological constant

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, resource-recommendations, cosmological-constant, adm-formalism

Does anyone know a reference in which the ADM equations for general relativity (the equations for the spatial metric and conjugate momentum or extrinsic curvature using the lapse and shift in the 3+1 decomposition) are stated with non-zero cosmological constant? I already checked the standard references like Misner, Thorne, Wheeler and the originial paper by Arnowitt, Deser and Misner. Also google does not provide me with any reference.